# Invalid JSON payload received when sending request to FCM API

Tags: php, json, curl, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm sending a request to FCM via my PHP app, but it returns the following error:

```
{ 
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. 
    Unknown name \"{\"validateOnly\":true,\"message\":{\"name\":\"testName\",\"token\":\"validToken\"}}\":
    Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{\"validateOnly\":true,\"message\":{\"name\":\"testName\",\"token\":\"validToken\"}}' 
    could not be found in request message.",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
"details": [ { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
"fieldViolations": [ 
   { "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. 
       Unknown name \"{\"validateOnly\":true,\"message\":{\"name\":\"testName\",\"token\":\"validToken\"}}\":
       Cannot bind query parameter.
       Field '{\"validateOnly\":true,\"message\":{\"name\":\"testName\",\"token\":\"validToken\"}}' could not be found in request message."
} ] } ] } }
```

**My notification**

```php
$notification = [
    'validateOnly' => true,
    'message' => [
        'name' => $name,
        'token' => "validToken"
    ]
];

$notification = json_encode($notification)
```

as JSON:

```
{ 
   "validateOnly":true,
   "message":{ 
      "name":"testName",
      "token":"validToken"
   }
}
```

**My http header**

```php
$header = [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Length' => strlen($notification),
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
];

$header = json_encode($header, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

as JSON:

```
{ 
   "Accept":"application/json",
   "Content-Length":72,
   "Content-Type":"application/json"
}
```

**My cURL code**

```
$curl_session = curl_init();
try {
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $this->_apiUrl);
    //_api_Url = https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectName/messages:send?access_token=$access_token
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $notification);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
$result = curl_exec($curl_session);
curl_close($curl_session);
```

My guess is that it's the first two quotes in `\"{\"validateOnly\"...` that's causing the issue. 
Is that possible? If so, how do you suggest I fix it? 
Any other ideas? As far as I can tell all my code is correct according to the [HTTP v1 docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your headers are wrong. This is not how php-curl expects them and because of that your request content type will be the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of seeing it as json. It should look like this:

```php
$header = [
    'Accept:application/json',
    'Content-Length:'.strlen($notification),
    'Content-Type:application/json',
];
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
```

and don't json encode it, just pass this to curl.

You can find this documented here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

> An array of HTTP header fields to set, in the format
>   array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')